# Layer 7 Load Balancing with on-premises exchange and Office 365

Tags: exchange, load-balancing, azure, microsoft-office-365

I would like to create essentially a layer 7 balanced redundant exchange setup where if the on-premises server fails it will automatically switch over to the office 365 Exchange services. I was wondering how can I do this. There doesn't seem to be an active mailbox database syncing method within office 365/Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***cannot*** replicate mailboxes between an on-premise database and Office 365, so even if you had an appropriate load-balancer, you won't have the actual data you want in both places.

Professional advice - ensure that you can do the foundational elements of your planned design before investigating the things that depend on those elements. You cannot assume a can-opener.

Comment: Appreciated, my plan was to do a co-location load balancing exchange with separated cas on a barracuda load balance service. But my superior is insisting on a 365 integration, hence the question.

Comment: You can't do it with O365. You can do of course do it with actual remote Exchange servers in your forest, whether they're built in Azure or other hosted infrastructure as VMs or racked in a remote colo.